# Trying to filter out lists in scala

Tags: scala

My requirement is as follows,

I have two classes lets say `A` and `B`.

```
case class A(id: String)

case class B(p1: Sting, p2: String)
```

Now, I have two sets.

```
val aSet: Set[A] = ...

val bSet: Set[B] = ...
```

Now, for every element in `aSet`, I want to find the Set of all `B's` from `bSet` such that,

```
a.id == b.p1 ++ b.p2
```

I have come up with following solution,

```
val myRequiredSet = aSet.map(a => bSet.filter(b => b.p1 ++ b.p2 == a.id))
```

My trouble is that the size of `aSet` is around 10,000 and the size of `bSet` is around 150,000.

Its taking a long long time and I am not able to come up with a better solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please post you code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com it doesn't belong to stackoverflow. flaging should be closed.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information about your code to answer this. For example, what type are your objects? Also, unless a.id is a collection, I think you messed up your parentheses.

Comment: @RamanMishra Although, the choice of words is kind of awkward. This looks like a genuine question. This often a problem with new users of SO, they struggle to correctly word their questions.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh actually it says need to improve performance of the code that means the code is working. And for optimization of the code we have a separate community which is codereview.

Comment: @RamanMishra This is not a matter of code-review. It is clearly a problem being faced by a new Scala programmer who is not able to explain his problem in better words. Anyone can take one look at that code and should be able to understand this.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh no where in the code i can see any problem nither logical nor technical so it's not that some new scala programmer who is not able to explain his problem it's clearly a matter of code review to improve the efficiency. If the code is not working or has some issue then we can say it's a noobie problem.

Comment: OP has clearly mentioned `idsIWant` set to have 10K elements and `idsToBeFilterd ` to have 150K element. If you can not see a problem in this code even after looking at the sizes and still consider this a code-review problem then I just don't want to argue with you any further then this. Lets close this discussion here.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh ok you are right i can't argue

Comment: @RamanMishra Its not that you can't argue. You can obviously. Its just that we both have different opinions on this matter. I have seen many new programmers facing such beginner issues but failing to word their problem in a correct way. Scala already has an awkward learning curve, we need to be more welcoming to the problems of our fellow programmers.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh ok thank you i will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Although, this question is kind of awkward. I am of the opinion that you are genuinely facing this issue. I will strongly advise you to put more effort into correctly wording your future questions, otherwise it will be ignored by people at SO.

Lets say you have following two classes.

```
case class A(id: String)

case class B(p1: String, p2: String)
```

You have these two sets,

```
val aSet: Set[A] = ...

val bSet: Set[B] = ...
```

In this case, for any instance of `A`, `id` is `p1 ++ p2` for corresponding instance of `B`.

Now, for all `A's` of `aSet`,You want to find the sets of `B's` having corresponding `p1` and `p2` from `bSet`.

```
val idToBMap = bSet.groupBy(b => b.p1 ++ b.p2)

val yourWantedSet: Set[Set[B]] = aSet.map(a => idToBMap.getOrElse(a.id, Set.empty[B]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it worked for me

```
val as=all.map( a=> ((a.name.get ++ a.someOtherName.get),a)).toMap
val result=smallerSet.map (a =>  as.get(a.id))
```